# Using Or Statement in pandas for assigning values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

df1

```
     a         b      c

0   Sussex    NaN     NaN
```

df2

```
     d         e      f       g

0   NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN
```

I'm trying to use a Or statement to assign the df3['i'] from either df1['a'] or df2['d']

My desired output:

df3

```
         i
 0      sussex
```

For a single value i assigned df3['i'] = df2['d']

Answer (score 0):

The question is not fully clear. What is i here? If df1['a'] or df2['d']  is the first iteration, is the second iteration df1['b'] or df2['e'] ? Where does the iteration end? Long winded solution and not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
def applymapfunction(df1,df2):
    df3 = pd.DataFrame()
    if not df1['a'].empty:
        df3[0] = df1['a']
        return df3
    else:
        df3[0]= df2['d']
        return df3

df3 =applymapfunction(df1,df2)
```

Comment: i wanted to use a Or statement to assign the df3['i']   from either df1['a'] or df2['d']

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df3['i'] = df2['d'].item() or df1['a'].item()
```

Or additional to @kerwei's answer you can also use `fillna`:

```
df3 = df1.fillna(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague but my guess is that you're trying to superimpose 2 data frames and the output would be a data frame where each cell is filled with values from either df1 or df2, whichever that is not empty. In this case, your column indexing for both data frames should match, such that:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['sussex'], 'b':[None], 'c':[None]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[None], 'b':[None], 'c':[None], 'd':[None]})

>>>df1.combine_first(df2)
        a     b     c   d
0  Sussex  None  None NaN
```